# cocos2d building in WIN7 vs2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cocos2d-x

I'm a learner of cocos2d-x,which is a open-source game engine.
but at the very beginning when I want to open the file I downloaded on cocos,
I suffered these problem

D:\game studio\cocos2d-x-3.0rc0\cocos\audio\proj.win32\CocosDenshion.vcxproj : error  : 未能完成操作。不支持此接口 (unable to do this operation,this interface is not supported)
and the rest 16 ones.

Cocos2D-X version: cocos2d-x v3.0r

IDE: Visual Studio 2013

Dependencies: python 2.7

I was told that my .net framework might be reinstalled to solve this problem
I tried but in vain

help me~

Comment: Title reads VS2013, question reads VS2012. Which is correct ?

Comment: so sorry,it is VS2013.

Comment: is there anyone can help me ~

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2d-x v3 supports Visual Studio 2012, see: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Windows

Comment: I was stuck in the very first step when I got these errors response.

Comment: I have also got some problem when starting cocos2d-x with VS2013, thanks for your manual.